# Wait for multiple for-each statements to be finished

Tags: javascript, arrays, asynchronous, foreach

I have an array of cluster, where each cluster contains a set of features. I use two forEach statements to iterate through the clusters and features in order to store each feature in my "result" array.

I need to further process my "result" array. But when I ask for the length of the array, it is stated, that the length is 0, although I can see in the console that there are features in it. I need to find a way to only process the "result" array when the forEach loops are finished.

I have read about this problem being caused through asynchronus data processing in JavaScript. I already tried to register a Promise, but I cannot get it to work, because in the examples always one forEach loop is used, but I have two forEach loops within each other.

This is my code:

```
var result = [];

clusters.forEach((cluster) => {
  getFeatures(cluster_id, (features) => {
  features.forEach((feature) => {
    result.push(feature);
  });
  });
});

//do something with result array
console.log("resulting features array length: " + result.length); //results in 0
```

Comment: Please click [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55363839/edit) then `[<>]` stacksnippet editor and produce a [mcve]

Comment: this is not enough information - please post `getFeatures()` implementation as well, just like `cluster`

Comment: i guess `getFeatures()` is async, something like a server request? in this case your `console.log()` will be executed before the http request was resolved

Comment: Please show us how you tried to use promises.

Comment: getFeatures() is most probably a http request, as the features are rendered from the map. I will provide more information and a stacksnippet tomorrow!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually don't need the inner forEach, as that just copies the features into result which can be done with `.push(...stuff)`, you have to promisify `getFeatures` to then be able to call `Promise.all` on all promises, to wait for them all to finish:

```
const result = [];

const allDone = Promise.all(clusters.map((cluster) => new Promise(resolve => {
  getFeatures(cluster_id, (features) => {
    result.push(...features);
    resolve();
  });
})));

allDone.then(() => {
  // result is ready to use here
});
```

In case you need the results in order, you could resolve the promises with them and flatten the result afterwards:

```
 const allDone = Promise.all(clusters.map((cluster) => new Promise(resolve => {
  getFeatures(cluster_id, (features) => {
    resolve(features);
  });
})));

allDone.then((nestedResults) => {
  const result = nestedResults.flat();
  //...
});
```

Comment: worked out perfectly well! although I still had to use the inner forEach, because I needed to access some feature attributes. However, your solution did the trick for me!

Answer (score 0):

You can convert results into a Promise, then flat the resolved arrays:

```
Promise.all(clusters.map(cluster => new Promise(resolve => 
    getFeatures(cluster.id, resolve)
  ))
)
// as .flat() doesn't work in Node.js <= 10, this is a workaround:
//.then(clusterFeatures => clusterFeatures.reduce((acc,curr) => [...acc, ...curr], []))
.then(clusterFeatures => clusterFeatures.flat())
.then(features => ... );
```

Comment: Just use `clusterFeatures.flat()`, not that inefficient `reduce` :-)

Comment: @Bergi I edited my answer - as a Node 10 user, I'm not used to using it.